# Correct SQL query statement requiring JOIN and UNION

Tags: sql, join, union

I was trying to solve this question (No. 29) on http://www.sql-ex.ru/

> Under the assumption that the income (inc) and expenses (out) of the
>   money at each outlet are written not more than once a day, get a
>   result set with the fields: point, date, income, expense. Use Income_o
>   and Outcome_o tables.

And came up with this solution

```
SELECT Income_o.point, Income_o.date, Income_o.inc, Outcome_o.out
FROM Income_o
INNER JOIN Outcome_o ON Income_o.point = Outcome_o.point
```

The result is obviously wrong (and hence my question here). It assumes that a point will never have more than 1 income and expense, so isn't this query correct? I can see from the same page that the correct query has some NULL column values. I would appreciate an explanation (if not the correct answer). My SQL is not a master one (and that's why I am trying to go through those!! So far done 29 out of 125 and only took help from SO on 3 of them)

The expected result is (From the website):

The result of correct query:

A snapshot of the expected result is here - http://snag.gy/yN43V.jpg

P.S. I know that the hint says UNION and JOIN and trying to get my head around this. If I can get the answer myself, I will post it.

Comment: The link requires account please post the query details with sample data and expected output.

Comment: If the LEFT table Income_o.point doesn't have a matching Outcome_o.point, the row will be discarded. That's your hint.

Answer (score 2):

You want a full outer join on `point` and `date`:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(i.point, o.point) AS point,
  COALESCE(i.date, o.date) AS date,
  i.inc,
  o.out
FROM
  Income_o AS i
  FULL JOIN Outcome_o AS o ON i.point = o.point AND i.date = o.date
;
```

The COALESCE expressions ensure that NULL is not returned for those columns: if the `Income_o` side has a NULL (because the table has no match for an `Outcome_o` row), the value is then taken from the other side.

Alternatively you can go with a union of two outer joins, left and right:

```
SELECT
  i.point,
  i.date,
  i.inc,
  o.out
FROM
  Income_o AS i
  LEFT JOIN Outcome_o AS o ON i.point = o.point AND i.date = o.date

UNION

SELECT
  o.point,
  o.date,
  i.inc,
  o.out
FROM
  Income_o AS i
  RIGHT JOIN Outcome_o AS o ON i.point = o.point AND i.date = o.date
;
```

If the tables have matches on the specified condition, both joins will return them, but UNION will eliminate duplicate entries. This second method is essentially an alternative implementation of full outer join, useful for cases where the FULL JOIN syntax is not supported. (MySQL is one product that does not support FULL JOIN.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Group By with Aggregate Function** to achieve the desired result, the sub query will combine the result set but will give results as per date, if there are two (in and out transaction) on same date, these will appear as two rows, to make it one row we can use Group By with aggregate function.

```
select point, date, max(inc), max(out)
from
(
select  point, date, inc, NULL as out
from    income_o
union all
select  point, date, NULL, out
from    outcome_o
)
dt 
group by point, date
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for LEFT JOIN

```
 SELECT Income_o.point, Income_o.dat, Income_o.inc, Outcome_o.outc
 FROM Income_o
LEFT JOIN Outcome_o ON Income_o.point = Outcome_o.point
```

try this [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23410/2)

Comment: Nope....this is certainly something I've tried already, but doesn't seem to be the correct one. I just checked it on sql-ex.ru

Comment: Well,there is maybe full outer join required but it is not clear from you question (is there always a record in Income_O table, or should there be records from outcome_o not matching the income_o?)

Comment: This doesn't get the desired results, FULL OUTER JOIN indeed is the solution.